# ffmpeg: unable to cut avi movie

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using ffmpeg to cut video file:

```
ffmpeg -<InputFile> -ss 00:00:00 -t 00:00:30 <OutputFile>
```

It's OK for different file formats exclude *.avi format. For avi movies ffmpeg shows that video is truncated, but output file contains full video (without truncating).
Does anybody know possible ways for problem troubleshooting?

Here converting command output for avi file:

```
FFmpeg version SVN-r26402, Copyright (c) 2000-2011 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Feb  1 2011 02:54:36 with gcc 4.4.5
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-nonfree --enable-postproc --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-x11grab
  libavutil     50.36. 0 / 50.36. 0
  libavcore      0.16. 1 /  0.16. 1
  libavcodec    52.108. 0 / 52.108. 0
  libavformat   52.93. 0 / 52.93. 0
  libavdevice   52. 2. 3 / 52. 2. 3
  libavfilter    1.74. 0 /  1.74. 0
  libswscale     0.12. 0 /  0.12. 0
  libpostproc   51. 2. 0 / 51. 2. 0
[mpeg4 @ 0x91e7e10] Invalid and inefficient vfw-avi packed B frames detected

Seems stream 0 codec frame rate differs from container frame rate: 30000.00 (30000/1) -> 25.00 (25/1)
Input #0, avi, from '/home/mightymeeting/Videos/tam-19.avi':
  Duration: 00:04:43.32, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 564 kb/s
    Stream #0.0: Video: mpeg4, yuv420p, 352x208 [PAR 1:1 DAR 22:13], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 30k tbc
    Stream #0.1: Audio: mp3, 32000 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 80 kb/s
[buffer @ 0x91e6ed0] w:352 h:208 pixfmt:yuv420p
Output #0, avi, to 'out.avi':
  Metadata:
    ISFT            : Lavf52.93.0
    Stream #0.0: Video: mpeg4, yuv420p, 352x208 [PAR 1:1 DAR 22:13], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
    Stream #0.1: Audio: mp2, 32000 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 64 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0.0 -> #0.0
  Stream #0.1 -> #0.1
Press [q] to stop encoding
[mpeg4 @ 0x91e7e10] Invalid and inefficient vfw-avi packed B frames detected
frame= 7082 fps=999 q=2.0 Lsize=    7513kB time=30.02 bitrate=2049.8kbits/s dup=0 drop=1    
video:7079kB audio:235kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead 2.718192%
```

Comment: How much extra video is being added? Having B-frames (especially if there's a problem with them) will need frames ahead of where you cut to be included.

Comment: to  Iain Ballard:   I want to cut a different videos, but only one *.avi file fails... The file output contain message "Invalid and inefficient vfw-avi packed B frames detected",< So I have a problems with B-frames.. Could you please explain me what is a B frames or give me link to B-frames description? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like this may be a DivX file. Try

```
ffmpeg -i INPUT.avi -c copy -ss 00:00:00 -t 00:00:30 -bsf:v mpeg4_unpack_bframes OUTPUT.avi
```

From the [documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-bitstream-filters.html#mpeg4_005funpack_005fbframes)

> DivX-style packed B-frames are not valid MPEG-4 and were only a
>   workaround for the broken Video for Windows subsystem. They use more
>   space, can cause minor AV sync issues, require more CPU power to
>   decode (unless the player has some decoded picture queue to compensate
>   the 2,0,2,0 frame per packet style) and cause trouble if copied into a
>   standard container like mp4 or mpeg-ps/ts, because MPEG-4 decoders may
>   not be able to decode them, since they are not valid MPEG-4.